# Can OpenVINO be used with AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, openvino

I was wondering. Could **OpenVINO** framework be used with AWS Lambda since it is so large in size? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see OpenVino is Python based so you can use it, as AWS Lambda supports it. Depending on the size, you may need to allocate more resources (memory) to the function execution environment - and this may affect the cost.

How?
You have to upload a package, which contains your lambda code plus all dependencies - in your case the OpenVino framework. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) are the AWS docs.

Answer (score 0):

But AWS Lambda restricts the size to only 250 mb and so we can't install OpenVINO on cloud. There is a Deployment Manager from OpenVINO which produces a Deployment Package but that does not support Python yet. So I am still not sure if OpenVINO can be used with AWS Lambda.